# how to repeat automatically pdf signature in every created page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

i'm making asp.net application that export table of data, but data table is large and automatically create a new pdf page

i need method that make signature automaticaly whenever creating new pdf page

```
        PdfFormField sig = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(s);
        sig.SetWidget(new Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), null);
        sig.FieldName = "testSignature";
        sig.Title = "testSTitle";
        sig.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
        sig.SetPage();
        sig.MKBorderColor = Color.BLACK;
        sig.MKBackgroundColor = Color.DARK_GRAY;
        PdfAppearance appearance = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(s, 72, 48);
        appearance.Rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, 71.5f, 47.5f);
        appearance.Stroke();
        sig.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, appearance);
        s.AddAnnotation(sig);
```

Comment: Do I read you correctly that you create a PDF document using iTextSharp with a large table in one run, and whenever a new page is created due to enough table items coming in, you want to sign the PDF created up to that moment?

Comment: yes that what i'm saying when i print the table with 10 rows as example it only take 1 pdfpage but if the table contain 20 rows it is automatically generate the 2nd page to view all data in table (but new pdf page without signature)

Comment: You'll run into one problem: As soon as you sign your PDF with one page, only a limited set of changes is allowed to the document, and adding content (e.g. additional table lines) is definitively forbidden. Or do I still understand you wrong and your merely want to add en empty signature field and not yet sign the document up to that point?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it in footer of your PDF, Below link may be useful.

http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx

Comment: thanks but Methods need kind of customization, but it is helpful